# Google maps fusion query escape & (ampersand)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm querying a fusion table:

```
SELECT Latitude,Longitude FROM myTable WHERE 'CompanyName' = 'Creek & Sons Co Ltd'
```

The problem is clearly the `&`, how does Google fusion tables query need to be escaped?

I am sending the query wrapped in `encodeURI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead, encodeURI does not encode the ampersand.

Comment: you must encode only the SELECT-statement with encodeURIComponent

Comment: I'm only using select statements. I tried encoding the entire statement and only the "where" part and have gotten bad request responses both times

Comment: ah I was encoding the entire call, not just the sql statement. Thank you!